# reverse geocodoing with tidygeocoder and OSM/Nominatim: How to get results in latin letters/English?

Tags: r, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I am reverse geocoding coordinates which pertain to addresses in countries where the Cyrillic alphabet is used. I am using `tidygeocoder` and `OSM/Nominatim` as a method. How can I modify my request in `tidygeocoder` to get the results/addresses not in Cyrillic but in Latin letters/in English?

As far as I can tell, the relevant property in the Nominatim/OSM API is `accept-language` (see [here](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Reverse/#language-of-results) and [here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/73250/nominatim-city-names)). But adding it to a tidygeocoder request seems not to work.

```
library(tidygeocoder)
library(tidyverse)

df_res <- tibble(
  lat=41.992073,
  long=21.429506
) %>% 
  reverse_geocode(.,
                  lat=lat,
                  long=long,
                  address="address",
                  method="osm")
```

The resulting address reads as

> Шпаркасе, Македонија, Водно, Центар, Скопје, Општина Центар, Град
> Скопје, Скопски СР, 1111, Северна Македонија

Modifying the request to (as suggested [here](https://jessecambon.github.io/tidygeocoder/reference/reverse_geo.html)):

```
tibble(
  lat=41.992073,
  long=21.429506
) %>% 
  reverse_geocode(.,
                  lat=lat,
                  long=long,
                  address="address",
                  method="osm",
                  api_options = list(osm_accept_language="en")
  )
```

leads to an error:

```
Error: Invalid parameter "osm_accept_language" used in the api_options argument. See ?reverse_geo
```

Any help? The error also occurs when using "osm_accept-language". Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a [reply](https://github.com/jessecambon/tidygeocoder/issues/159) from the package author on github I found the answer:

```
df_res <- tibble(
  lat=41.992073,
  long=21.429506
) %>% 
  reverse_geocode(.,
                  lat=lat,
                  long=long,
                  address="address",
                  method="osm",
                  custom_query  = list("accept-language"="en-US"))
```